# how to fscanf correctly in c when reading a line like 1,2,3,4?

Tags: c, file-io, input, output

```
void readFile(void) {

    FILE *file;    
    int i;
    char line[100];
    int testnr, testnr2, testnr3, testnr4;
    //testnr = 1;
    //testnr2 = 2;
    //testnr3 = 3;
    //testnr4 = 4;

    file = fopen("test.txt","r");

    fgets(line,500,file); // does not do anything with the first line

    // read in 1,2,3,4
    fscanf(file, "%i %i %i %i", &testnr, &testnr2, &testnr3, &testnr4);      
    printf("%i %i %i %i \n", testnr, testnr2, testnr3, testnr4);    

    fclose(file);
}
```

The output in the terminal becomes: `1 32714 -275292160 32767`

How can i fix it so it is: `1 2 3 4` ?

Comment: Side note: `char line[100]; ... fgets(line,500,file);` is a problem.  Suggest `fgets(line, sizeof line,file);` - much safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read in the characters between the integers too.

```
fscanf( file, "%i,%i,%i,%i", &nr, &nr2, &nr3, &nr4 );
```

Also note, `fscanf` returns the number of successful reads. So you could do:

```
int num_reads = fscanf( file, "%i,%i,%i,%i", ... );
if( num_reads != 4 ) 
{
    // DO ERROR
}
else
{
    // DO SUCCESS
}
```